# Unresolved reference of a Kotlin extension function in the Gradle build

Tags: gradle, extension-methods, kotlin

I have multi project Gradle build with all the code written in Kotlin. There are two projects in it: common and client. Subprojects are in the intermediate folder, say "demo". So the folder structure is:

```
project
  demo
    client
      build.gradle
    common
      build.gradle
  build.gradle
  gradle.properties
  settings.gradle
```

The settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'demo'

include 'demo/client'
include 'demo/common'
```

Client dependes on the common project `compile project(":demo/common")`. And there is an extension function in the common project:

```
fun <T> List<Future<T>>.getAll(): Long {
    var count = 0L
    this.forEach {
        it.get()
        count++
    }
    return count
}
```

If I try to use it in the client project I get `Unresolved reference: getAll` exception at the compilation time. The usage:

```
...
import org.sandbox.imdg.hazelcast.common.utils.getAll

class CassLoader {

    fun loadCalcData(): Long {
        ...
        val futures: List<Future<CalcData>> = items.map { map.putAsync(it.getKey(), it) }
        return futures.getAll()
    }
}
```

At the same time everything compile fine if I put the `getAll` declaration in the client project. I'm pretty sure that the import of the function is correct but at the same time I had a little experience with Gradle so might miss something.

- Build: `gradlew clean build`
- Kotlin: 1.0.2
- Gradle: 2.9

UPD: The problem is in the folder structure (or may be I'm declaring dependencies wrong...) - if I remove intermediate folder demo everytning is ok.

Comment: The magical `clean`/`build` solved this issue for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem was in the wrong subproject includes in the gradle.settings. Should be

```
include 'demo:common'
include 'demo:client'
```

instead of

```
include 'demo/common'
include 'demo/client'
```

and then for the dependency `compile project(":demo:common")`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you included both projects in root `settings.gradle`.

Check [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/madhead/0d17d0d749834bc521657cff33df628b) with minimal working setup.

**settings.gradle**:

```
rootProject.name = 'demo'

include 'client'
include 'common'
```

**build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://repository.jetbrains.com/all"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}
```

**common/src/main/kotlin/by/dev/madhead/demo/common/Funktions.kt**

```
package by.dev.madhead.demo.common

fun String.revert(): String {
    return this.reversed()
}
```

**client/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':common')
}
```

**client/src/main/kotlin/by/dev/madhead/demo/client/App.kt**

```
package by.dev.madhead.demo.client

import by.dev.madhead.demo.common.revert

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello".revert())
}
```

Comment: Still have no success with it. Everything compiles fine if the extension is in the client subproject and then breaks when I move it in the client subproject. Both subprojects are included in the settings.gradle. Upd: but everything is ok in your setup - I should check if there are any diffs.

Comment: The problem is in the structure of the project. I have an intermediate folder (say "demo") in the project and the common and client folder in it. Updated the question to reflect that fact.